# PhoneGap IOS native datepicker plugin showing an error in Phonegap 2.2.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap 2.2.0 and jquery moble 1.3.1 for my IOS app, but Native datepicker showing an error (CDVPlugin.h not found)

This is the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most phonegap plugins need to be updated to work on phonegap 2.7.0

Here you have the [plugin upgrade guide](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md)

Comment: I am changed phonegap version to 2.2.0 but i have the same problem..:(

Comment: Follow the guide, but AFAIK, you can delete the line with the error and the plugin should work, delete the ifdef line, the else end endif